# text-align not working on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, text-align

I'm having some wierd css issue making a website for a client which only occur if using google chrome. on firefox, explorer and edge, it does work fine.

Basicly, some code I used several times in the same page, works everytime except for one. I really cannot see where I did wrong:

```
<h2 class="big caps" style="text-align:left">WHAT WILL YOU LEARN?</h2>
```

[page is here](http://www.vemes-distribution.com/mctest/workshops.php): if you scroll down to the middle of the page you'll see what i'm talking about. look at it with google chrome first, and then with any other browser. (or source code @ line 370)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your div position is wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your `.one_full` class like below

```
.one_full {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to .one_full class `clear:both` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can add float:left or clear:both to .one_full

```
.one_full {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    /*or float: left;*/
}
```